# Remove imported localized data

Tags: powershell, localization

How do I remove localized data in PowerShell?

Say that I have imported localized strings for a script and then want to remove this to be able to import it again.

I haven't found any cmdlet for it and don't know if this is saved in $host and can be removed there.

The data is imported, with the following:

```
Import-LocalizedData -BindingVariable msgTable -FileName $SomePSDataFile -BaseDirectory $SomeNeighbouringFolder
```

Comment: This is unclear.. Show us your code. How did you import these strings? In an array or as separate variables or...

Comment: `$msgTable = $null` ? `Remove-Variable msgTable` ?

Comment: Yes, of course... Silly me was thinking that it was put somewhere else, not in the variable that I specify, and can delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you have imported the strings as variables, you should be able to clear them using the `Clear-Variable` command.

PowerShell stores its variables on a drive called `Variable:`. You can treat this like a normal drive and list the variables using a `dir` or a `Get-ChildItem`, for example, `dir Variable:\` will return all your currently defined variables.

You can then clear the variables you want with the `Clear-Variable` command. You provide this command with the variable name without the `$` sign in front of it.